# JList update UI

Tags: java, swing, vector, jlist

So I have been trying to update JList using DefaultListModel. Now I have seen online examples and made a function to update the model. The problem I'm facing is that the model is being updated but not the UI even after calling the updateUI() method. Here is my code.

```
 public void updateAthleteList() {

 System.out.println("Trying to update");
 //call updateUI() for the JList object
 athletesModel.clear();
 System.out.println(athleteList.size());
 for(int i = 0; i < athleteList.size(); i++) {

     System.out.println("Inside loop");
     athletesModel.addElement(((Athlete) athleteList.get(i)).toStringCount());
 }

 athletesList.updateUI();
 System.out.println(athletesModel.size());
 System.out.println(athletesList.getModel().getSize());
}
```

The output lines were just there to debug. I would really appreciate if I could get any help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have worked with simple strings this time and the model is being updated as I printed out the size but still no change in JList. Here is my code

```
public void updateAthleteList(Athlete newAthlete)
 {
    System.out.println("Trying to update");
    //call updateUI() for the JList object
    DefaultListModel tempModel = (DefaultListModel)athletesList.getModel();
    tempModel.addElement("hij");
    System.out.println(athletesList.getModel().getSize());
    athletesList.setModel(tempModel);
    athletesList.updateUI();
    System.out.println(athletesList.getModel().getSize());
 }
```

Comment: There is never any need to invoke the updateUI() method. All you need to do is update the model. If the JList doesn't update then that means either 1) the model doesn't belong to a JList that is displayed on your frame or 2) you didn't update the model on the Event Dispatch Thread. The problem is in the code you don't post. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is, create a simple GUI with a JList and a button with an action listener to add an item to the model. Prove that simple code works and then fix your real program.

Comment: Ok I will try that but I read somewhere that you shouldn't update Vector directly instead update the model. What I am doing is that I'm updating the vector from one panel and then passing it to other panel where I'm updating the model. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes you need to update the model. You haven't posted a `SSCCE` so I can't help with any more suggestions.

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the model directly instead of updating the vector. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

sets the model JList somewhere? perhaps in its constructor

```
JList s = new JList();
DefaultListModel x =  (DefaultListModel) s.getModel(); //
```

or after his for

```
//change athletesList.updateUI(); 
jList.setModel(athletesModel);
```

Comment: Sorry no luck. I did set the model in the constructor and I don't think that is the problem. When I update my model and I call out function     athletesList.getModel().getSize() it gives me correct size of model but doesn't update UI

Comment: There is no need to use a repaint(). When you update the model the JList will repaint itself automatically.

Comment: I found the problem. I was calling the function to update JList from another class where I was making a new object every time. I changed that now and object is created once and every time the size of model increases but still I couldn't see the updated JList. I have updated the code and hope you can take a look at it @camickr